# session variable keeps overriding in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

In my php code I am trying to collect some data each time a user clicks a particular button. However even though the data is avaiable everytime the button is executed only the latest data is added to the array.
How can I keep adding this new data while keeping the old data

```
$session_data['items'] = array('id' => $id,'price' => $price);
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

edit

Updated code with suggested answer however still no outcome

```
$session_data['items'][]= array('id' => $id,'price' => $price);
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

Comment: You need a 2-dimensional array, and you can push the new nested array onto it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an 2-dimensional array data type. This way, you can have a lot of data inserted and get the latest value too.

```
$session_data['items'][] = array('id' => $id, 'price' => $price);
$session_data['items'][] = array('id' => $id, 'price' => $price + 1);
```

If you keep adding it the above way, it pushes new data to the end. In the above code, both the values are saved.

Answer (score 0):

Use CodeIgnighter's `push()` method to add to a session variable that contains an array.

```
$this->session->push('items', array('id' => $id, 'price' => $price));
```

Comment: I have updated the question with how my code looks now

Comment: Make sure the rest of the script uses the session variable consistently with this.

Comment: I am just testing it out currently and I am setting it using the code in the question and testing it out from another controller using

 echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->session->addedItems);
echo "</pre>";

Comment: What is `addedItems` and how is it related to `items`?

Comment: What is `$this->session`? Are you using a framework that defines these classes?

Comment: oh sorry its a typo it should be 'items' not 'addedItems'

Comment: Use its built-in `push()` method. I've updated the answer.

Comment: According to the documentation, the userdata methods are obsolete. See https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html.